# Snipping tool that makes a icon without a border

Tags: windows, photography

I'm looking for a program that can take a .png (any format really) and store an icon in a certain spot in my screen. Snipping tool is perfect....except it can't put the picture on my screen and goes to the back when I focus a different window. I think the best explanation would be like a Photoshop layer but with my active Windows screens being on layer 2.

I need it to not have a border (no windows borders with the X, etc.), to stay on top of other content even if it's not the focus, and for the content I use to be user-generated.

Bonus points if I can use moving images.

Comment: Maybe you tell us what you want to achieve. Do you want to fool someone? An icon somewhere on the screen without doing anyhing - I am missing the use case

Comment: What do you mean by "moving images"? Do you want it to be animated or do you want the icon to walk around on the screen?

Comment: It's going to be used for multiple things including but not limited to: pranking a friend, forcing outdated programming code to work (application got updated, the code running on it didn't, requires a specific "look" I guess), SOP creation (arrows mainly, but a few other shapes), coaching for games, and for other more general use.

Comment: So, when clicking on that fake icon, what should happen? Technically, the click goes to the image and is gone. If you want to change the look and feel of an application, do you need the click to be forwarded to the application that is below the icon?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what happens to it for my use cases, but ideally nothing happens until the application is closed (click goes through to the app or whatever is below).